# RHEL 6 No protocol specified, can't open display

Tags: rhel6

I got this when I try to open nco_event in RHEL 6.3

```
[netcool@noi bin64]$ nco_event&
[1] 19962
[netcool@noi bin64]$ No protocol specified
Fatal Error:  /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/omnibus/platform/linux2x86/bin64/nco_event: can't open display
```

Any idea to solved that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Putty & Xming to connect to this machine? 
If not, check the Xorg server on your client. 
You can also check the $DISPLAY variable

Answer (score 7):

When executing the command `xhost`, you are probably receiving

```
No protocol specified
xhost: unable to open display ":0"
```

Issue is your user is not allowed to access the X server.

You can use xhost to limit access for X server for security reasons.

Switch back to default user and execute xhost again. You should see something like

```
SI:localuser:nuwan
```

The solution is to add the oracle to access control list

```
xhost +SI:localuser:youruser
```

Now switch back to original user "youruser". It should be working now.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, I had a similar issue and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this while while launching Xming :

Launch Xming and select the style you wish to display the X server output. 
Hint:

- Select Multiple Windows and your X applications will look like they were launched from Windows.
- Leave Display number set to 0 Click Next.
- Select Start No Client and click Next.
- **On Server Options, check the box title Disable Server Control. Leaving the box unchecked can give you an "unspecified protocol error" later down the road.**
- Click Next and save your configuration.

This will create a quick way to launch Xming later.

This will solve "No protocol specified" error .

Thanks.